# How can i find the transmission rate of my wifi direct connection?

Tags: android

I use the following code to find the rate of wifi connection.

```
public int getWifiRate()
{
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wi = wm.getConnectionInfo();
    int linkRate = wi.getLinkSpeed();
    return linkRate;
}
```

I want to know if there is a similar way to find the rate of an existing wifi direct connection.

Thank you very much